# Please help! How to express the cases in if clause?

Tags: php

I have string `$a,$b,$c`

I know if all of them not null express in this way:

```
if($a!="" && $b!="" && $c!="")
```

But if either 2 of them not null then go into the true caluse

```
if($a!="" && $b!="" && $c!=""){
** do the things here **
}else if(either 2 are not null){
**do another things here**
}
```

How to express it?

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simple function like this to check:

```
function checkInput($var)
{
    $nulls=0;
    foreach($var as $val)
    {
        if(empty($val))
        {
            $nulls++;
        }
    }
    return $nulls;
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
$inputs=array($a, $b, $c.... $z);
$nullCount=checkInput($inputs);

if($nullCount==0)
{
    // All nulls
}

if($nullCount>2)
{
    // More than 2 nulls
}
```

or for an one-off test, just pop the function into the actual if statement like this:

```
if(checkInput($inputs)>2)
{
    // More than 2 nulls...
}
```

etc etc. You can then use the one function to check for any number of nulls in any number of variables without doing much work - not to mention change it without having to rewrite a long if statement if you want to modify it.

Comment: Store checkInput in a variable so you don't have to call it twice and iterate through the loop twice. Saves a bit of CPU Clock Cycles.

Comment: Looks like we got into same solution at same time ;)

Comment: @ex3v Seems that way :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good, but you can expand this to easily handle more variables:

```
$variables = array($a, $b, $c, $d, ....);

$howManyNulls = 0;

foreach($variables as $v){
    if($v == ''){
       $howManyNulls++;
    }
}

if($howManyNulls == count($variables) - 2){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if($a!="" && $b!="" && $c!="")
{
    ** do the things here **
}
else if(($a!="" && $b!="") || ($b!="" && $c!="") || ($a!="" && $c!=""))
{
    **do another things here**
}
```

Comment: @SuenFalendo Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($a!="" && $b!="" && $c!=""){
** do the things here **
}else if(($a!="" && $b!="") || ($a!="" && $c!="") || ($b!="" && $c!="")){
**do another things here**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var[] = empty($a) ? 0:$a;
$var[] = empty($b) ? 0:$b;
$var[] = empty($c) ? 0:$c;

$varm  = array_count_values($var);
if ($varm[0] === 0) {
    //Code for when all aren't empty!
} elseif ($varm[0] === 1) {
    //Code for when two aren't empty!
}
```

N.B; You may need to replace the 0 for a string/integer that will never crop up, if your variables are always strings or empty then 0 will do for this. The method for using bools within this would require more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nullCount = 0
if($a!=""){ ++$nullCount; }
if($b!=""){ ++$nullCount; }
if($c!=""){ ++$nullCount; }

if($nullCount == 3){ // all are null
  // do smth
}else if($nullCount == 2){ // only two are null
  // do other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's something potentially maintainable, should the list of arguments increase:

```
function countGoodValues(...$values) {
   $count = 0;
   foreach($values as $value) {
      if($value != "") {
         ++$count;
      }
   }
   return $count;
}

$goodValues = countGoodValues($a, $b, $c); // Or more... or less
if($goodValues == 3) {
    // Do something here
}
else if($goodValues == 2) {
    // And something else
}
```

[Reference for the ... construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-174) (examples #7 and #8 in particular) are available on php.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double typecasting (to boolean, then to number) in conjunction with summing:

```
$count = (bool)$a + (bool)$b + (bool)$c;
if ($count == 3)
// ** do the things here **
else if ($count == 2)
//**do another things here**
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also possible such solution:

```
<?php

$a= 'd';
$b = 'a';
$c = '';     

$arr = array( (int) ($a!=""), (int) ($b!=""), (int) ($c!=""));

$occ = array_count_values($arr);


if ($occ[1] == 3) {
  echo "first";
} 
else if($occ[1] == 2) {
   echo "second";
}
```

If you have 3 variables as in your example you can probably use simple comparisons, but if you have 4 or more variables you would get too big condition that couldn't be read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($a!="") + ($b!="") + ($c!="") == 2) {
    // two of the variables are not empty
}
```

The expression a!="" should return true (which is 1 as an integer) when the string is not empty. When you sum whether each of the strings meets this condition, you get the number of non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count(array_filter([$a, $b, $c])) >= 2) ...
```

This is `true` if at least two of the variables are *truthy*. That means `$var == true` is `true`, which may be slightly different than `$var != ""`. If you require `!= ""`, write it as test:

```
if (count(array_filter([$a, $b, $c], function ($var) { return $var != ""; })) >= 2) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($a!="" && $b!="" && $c!="") {
    echo "All notnull";
} elseif(($a!="" && $b!="") || ($b!="" && $c!="") || ($a!="" && $c!="")) {
    echo "Either 2 notnull";
}
```